# Looped binary sorting tree

Tags: computational-geometry, binary-search-trees

I want to add a points one by one into sorting tree. I have *less then* function to order them by angle from absciss: for points $\mathbf p_i = (x_i,y_i)$ and $\mathbf p_j = (x_j,y_j)$ it just sign of cross product of radius vectors to them:

$$
f_<(\mathbf p_i, \mathbf p_j) \stackrel{def}{\equiv} (x_i \cdot y_j < x_j \cdot y_i)
$$

How can I modify RB tree implementation (or is there more general approach for any sorting tree) to make it looped (i.e. modulo $2 \pi$)? Is there "symmetrical" approach to make tree equally well arranged with no dependence on direction for points in general positions?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it looped"?  What are you taking modulo $2\pi$?  If you just use the ordering directly without doing anything to "make it looped" is there some requirement that is violated?  I'm having difficulty understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @D.W. On usual invariant for BST is `!(least_element > greatest_element)`. It violated in case of modular arithmetic.

Comment: I know that, but I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish.  What number/value do you want to apply modular arithmetic to?  How will you recognize a valid answer?  What requirements must it satisfy?  Why is it a problem if you don't use "modulo" but just sort the points according to the "less than" function you defined?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It looks like you mean something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order - and it's not a binary relation

Comment: Also you need to define operations on data structure you are trying to develop - it will help you to understand how you need to store your data points

Comment: A little later I will present you the results of my research.